# Star Trek Discovery and the origin of "The Burn"

Tags: geometry

This maths puzzle was inspired by watching the latest season of Star Trek Discovery.

**Warning:** minor spoilers for season 3 of Star Trek Discovery ahead.

Many years ago, something caused hundreds to starships across the galaxy to explode. For the longest time it was thought this had occurred at exactly the same time throughout the galaxy, despite how odd this may seem. But one day Michael Burnham, chief science officer of USS Discovery, recovered the black boxes of two of the destroyed ships and noticed that they hadn't quite been destroyed at the same time.
"Hang on" -- she thought -- "if I can get my hands on a third black box, I might be able to pinpoint the location of the source of the signal that caused the ships to explode."

How can she locate the origin of the signal? What is the minimum number of black boxes required?

Some clarifications:

- We assume that some signal caused the spaceships to instantly detonate when it reached them.
- We assume it was sent from somewhere in the physical realm and that it spread through space at a constant velocity uniformly in every direction.
- One might be tempted to assume this velocity is the speed of light; however if that were the case it would have been noticed long before. Therefore the speed of propagation is taken as an unknown.
- Each black box contains the spatial coordinates of the ship and the time at which it received the signal. Note however that we don't know at what time the signal was originated.
- Don't think for a second I'm taking relativity into account :)

Comment: "Don't think for a second I'm taking relativity into account"... That was clear since the beginning, because "this had occurred at exactly the same time throughout the galaxy" is physically meaningless.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I guess you're right. I'm no physicist or mathematician, and relativity is something I still have to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 1):

## Attempt at a solution

After thinking about this problem for some time I believe I have come up with a (partial) solution.

We can think of each black box as representing a point in a four-dimensional space, with time being the fourth coordinate. Then the signal can be thought of as a 4D cone, with the vertex at the source of the signal, and the surface representing the points in spacetime at which other ships receive the signal. We know that the cone has a <del>circular</del> spherical base (we assume the velocity of propagation is uniform in every direction) and that it is aligned with the time axis, so it is a so-called *right circular* cone. It helps to visualize the problem as having two spatial dimensions plus one in time (see image).

[image]

After some digging I [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone#Equation_form) the following equation form of a circular cone with its apex at the origin, aligned with the vector $\vec d$ and aperture $2\theta$:
$$
F(\vec u) = (\vec u \cdot \vec d)^2 - (\vec d \cdot \vec d)(\vec u \cdot \vec u)(\cos\theta)^2 = 0
$$

We know that our cone is aligned with the time axis, so $\vec d = [0\, 0\, 0\, 1]^T$, however we don't know the location of the apex, so we will replace $\vec u$ with $\vec u - \vec x$, where $\vec x$ are the spacetime coordinates of the source, and $\vec u$ of a black box:
\begin{align}
F(\vec u - \vec x) &= ((\vec u - \vec x) \cdot \vec d)^2 - (\vec d \cdot \vec d)((\vec u - \vec x) \cdot (\vec u - \vec x))(\cos\theta)^2\\
&= (u_t - x_t)^2 - ||\vec u - \vec x||^2(\cos\theta)^2 = 0
\end{align}

Now we have one equation and five unknowns: three spatial coordinates, one temporal coordinate, and the cone's aperture $\theta$, which is effectively the velocity at which the signal propagates. This suggests we need at least five black boxes to uniquely solve the problem.

Caveats:

- I am casually extending the above formula to four dimensions. Not sure if that works.
- Not just any 5 points will do: if, for instance, these 5 points lie on a line in 4D space, the system of equations will be underdefined.
- I don't know whether this could be solved with fewer than five points.